# What widget(s) should be used for creating rows after named section in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to implement rows after named section, something like in Android phone contacts:

[image]

I mean a section name (for example `* Favorites`) and one or more rows after this name (`TechBone net`). Could anyone say what widget(s) should be used in Flutter for such task?

Comment: What have you tried? You can use a column that contains rows for each letter

Comment: I think https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_sticky_header is good enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use MixedList by customising this example ([provided by Flutter Official Documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/lists/mixed-list#interactive-example))

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(
    MyApp(
      items: List<ListItem>.generate(
        1000,
        (i) => i % 6 == 0
            ? HeadingItem('Alphabet $i')
            : MessageItem('Contact $i', 'Number $i'),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<ListItem> items;

  const MyApp({super.key, required this.items});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    const title = 'Mixed List';

    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text(title),
        ),
        body: ListView.builder(
          // Let the ListView know how many items it needs to build.
          itemCount: items.length,
          // Provide a builder function. This is where the magic happens.
          // Convert each item into a widget based on the type of item it is.
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            final item = items[index];

            return ListTile(
              title: item.buildTitle(context),
              subtitle: item.buildSubtitle(context),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// The base class for the different types of items the list can contain.
abstract class ListItem {
  /// The title line to show in a list item.
  Widget buildTitle(BuildContext context);

  /// The subtitle line, if any, to show in a list item.
  Widget buildSubtitle(BuildContext context);
}

/// A ListItem that contains data to display a heading.
class HeadingItem implements ListItem {
  final String heading;

  HeadingItem(this.heading);

  @override
  Widget buildTitle(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(
      heading,
      style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.headline6,
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget buildSubtitle(BuildContext context) => const SizedBox.shrink();
}

/// A ListItem that contains data to display a message.
class MessageItem implements ListItem {
  final String sender;
  final String body;

  MessageItem(this.sender, this.body);

  @override
  Widget buildTitle(BuildContext context) => Text(sender);

  @override
  Widget buildSubtitle(BuildContext context) => Text(body);
}
```

Do check it out, it might help you.

Comment: You can customise ListTile Widget or use Row & Column Combination for that. @Pavel_K

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you out. If so, I would appreciate if you could accept my answer  If you still have questions, feel free to ask 